# Using REST root resource class as interface, getting "no operation matching request"

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat7, cxf, m2eclipse

**Problem:** Root resource class defined as interface with all annotations. CXFServlet is not able to see the POST operation on the impl class, though it's defined on the interface. **When all the annotations are copied into the impl class, it works fine.**

**Note:** The GET works fine when only defined on the interface, only the POST is causing the problem.

```
@Path("foo/")
public interface TestService {
    @Path("foo/{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getIt(String id);

@Path("foo")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ElementClass(response = Bar.class)
public Response createStuff(@Context MessageContext context,
        Bar bar);
```

}

```
@Features(features = "org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature")  
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
    @Override
    public String getIt(String id) {
        return "Hi there!";
    }
@Override
public Response createStuff(@Context MessageContext context,
        Bar bar) {
    bar.set...
    bar.set...
    return Response.ok(bar).build();
```

}

**Beans.xml** 
{

```
<jaxrs:server id="testService" address="/test">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="testservice1"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <bean id="testservice1" class="foo.bar.TestServiceImpl"/>
```

}

**Web.xml**

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    ……..
    </listener>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Reuest printed from Tomcat7.0 server:**
Using Chrome Postman

### INFO: Inbound Message

ID: 1

```
Address: http://localhost:8080/<war-name>/test/foo/foo
Encoding: ISO-8859-1
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], accept-encoding=[gzip,deflate,sdch], accept-language=[en-US,en;q=0.8], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[144], content-type=[application/json], host=[localhost:8080], origin=[chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36]}
Payload: {
    "bar": {
        "create_time": "Fri Sep 20 17:51:40 PDT 2013",
        "update_time": "e0739141-1e8c-48ad-b8ad-410331b3dba3",
    }
}
```

**Error:**
Sep 21, 2013 12:13:05 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils findTargetMethod
WARNING: **No operation matching request path "//test/foo/foo" is found,** Relative Path: /foo, HTTP Method: POST, ContentType: application/json, Accept: */*,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
Sep 21, 2013 12:13:05 PM org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor

```
INFO: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 404
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Allow=[GET, OPTIONS, HEAD], Date=[Sat, 21 Sep 2013 19:13:05 GMT], Content-Length=[0]}
```

---

Comment: How exactly do you send the response? Can you change `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` to `@Produces("text/plain")`

Answer (score 6):

I figured out the problem myself. In the imll class methods, don't re-declare the params with annotations.

In this snippet inside the Impl class

```
@Override
public Response createStuff(*@Context* MessageContext context,
        Bar bar) {
```

I used the ***@Context*** annotation unnecessarily, which is throwing it off. Once I remove the annotation from the impl class, it works just fine. And rightly so, why to decorate the method params again when you specified it in the interface.